# Python code to read csv file and get counts for groups based on wildcard value

Tags: python

```
client_id   visittype
1           Comprehensive Eval
1           Psychotherapy
1           Case Management
2           CM Eval
3           Comprehensive Eval
3           Case Management
3           Psychotherapy
4           Comprehensive Eval
5           Comprehensive Eval
5           Psychotherapy
```

I’m new to Python. I need to read a csv file with the two columns above.  I need a count of each `client_id` that has at least one `visittype` entry other than an entry with ‘Eval’ in the name.  Even if a `client_id` has more than one entry other than ‘%Eval%’, it should only be counted once. I’ll also need a count of the `client_ids` that do not have a `visittype` other than ‘%Eval%’. And, I need the averages for both.

In the above sample, `client_ids` 1, 3, and 5 will count as having the qualifying entry. 2 and 4 will not.

Total with: 3
Total without: 2

The logic will be something like:

```
For each client_id
 If visittype NOT like '%Eval%'
      with_count += 1
     client_count +=1
 else
     without_count +=1
     client_count +=1
 endif

avg_with = with_count/client_count
avg_without = without_count/client_count
```

I realize that is not Python syntax.

I usually post code that I’ve tried when asking a question. I’m choosing not to do that this time since it turned into a mess.

Thanks in advance for any help. Feel free to post links to similar code that would help in learning Python.

Comment: I edited the if statement in my pseudocode to: If visittype NOT like '%Eval%'. I had omitted the 'NOT' when I first posted. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: your problem is not clear for me. can you give us the resulting `with_count` and `without_count` using your simple example ?

Comment: Regardless of how messy it is, showing your attempt will give people a better idea of what exactly you got stuck on, and can help get you higher quality answers.

Comment: with_count = 3, without_count = 2

Comment: The csv file is the output from a sql query for clients that have had a visittype with 'Eval' in the name. The other visittypes for each client are followup visits. I'm basically getting counts of clients with evaluations that have had followup visits. That is why I am checking for visittypes without 'Eval' in the name. I don't know if that makes it clearer.

Comment: I agree that I should post some code. I'll see if I can get something readable together.

Comment: did you try the pandas library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the pandas library ?
If I understand your issue, you can try this (no use of loops here)

```
#import the library & read your file
import pandas as pd
temp = pd.read_csv("path/to/your/file/your_file.csv")
# your condition is : "the type contains "Eval"" 
condition = temp["visittype"].str.contains("Eval")
with_count = temp.loc[~condition, "client_id"].unique()
# get the list of non "Eval" count
without_count = list(set(temp.loc[condition, "client_id"].unique()) - set(with_count))
client_count = len(temp.client_id.unique())
avg_with = len(with_count) / client_count
avg_witout = len(without_count) / client_count
```

Comment: Nice answer with pandas. But why not use groupby after you condition in your pandas df?

Comment: Groupby.Series apply have the groupby column as index. So it should work

Comment: J. Doe, That is exactly what I need. That works. I was working with pandas the other day but wasn't sure how to work in the conditions. I had attempted to use a wildcard. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

A Python-Version of your Pseudo-Code would be like this:

```
for client in clients:
    if not "Eval" in client:
        with_count += 1
    else:
        without_count += 1
    client_count += 1
avg_with = with_count / client_count
avg_witout = without_count / client_count
```

clients would be some kind of iterable from your csv and client would be from type string.

To address your only counted once problem, you could use an array and push the user_id of counted entries into it.

```
counted = []
for i in range(clients):
    if not "Eval" in clients[i].visittype and not clients[i].client_id in counted:
        with_count += 1
        counted.append(client.id)
    else:
        without_count += 1
    client_count += 1
avg_with = with_count / client_count
avg_witout = without_count / client_count
```

Since we don't know how the structure of the data is you get from the csv, we cannot know how to implement it besides from theory.

Comment: Thanks, LS. I'll try to work from that. I only need to count the client once even if it has more than one visittype other than '%Eval%'. I might have to use break after the count to keep it from being counted again.

Comment: The csv is comma delimited. I don't know how relevant that is.

Comment: Thanks to all that replied. All of these answers are helpful. I marked one as the answer but will come back and finish trying all of the others to get them to work. I realize I wasn't as clear with my question as I could have been.

Comment: I'm using this code as well as code from two other answers. Thanks. i wish I could mark more than one answer as correct.

Comment: You could even create your own answer and mark that as correct if it is better in answering your initial question. This way, someone with the same problem as the initial problem can find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution by reading the data into a python dictionary, and then iterating over the keys (Patient ID).

```
import csv
with open("data.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    patient_dict = {}
    for line in reader:
        key = line[0]
        patient_id = line[1]
        if key not in patient_dict:
            patient_dict[key] = []
        patient_dict[key].append(patient_id)
```

Here the output:

```
{'1': ['Comprehensive Eval', ' Psychotherapy', 'Case Management'],
 '2': ['CM Eval'],
 '3': ['Comprehensive Eval', 'Case Management', 'Psychotherapy'],
 '4': ['Comprehensive Eval'],
 '5': ['Comprehensive Eval', ' Psychotherapy']}
```

Here's the rest of it

```
with_counter = 0
without_counter = 0
for k, v in patient_dict.items():
    for item in v:
        if 'Eval' not in item:
            with_counter = with_counter + 1
            break
    else:
        without_counter = without_counter + 1

print('With = ' + str(with_counter))
print('Without = ' + str(without_counter))

#With = 3
#Without = 2
```

Comment: Nice, you could chain this into my answer :P

Comment: Thanks. I'll be using something like this when my code gets more complex. I might use it along with pandas.